# How force BeanPostProcessor proxy to look up on classes not interfaces?

Tags: java, spring, proxy

I am not sure if question is correctly asked because I am still newbie in this stuff.

I want to complete the following scenario using a `BeanPostProcessor`:

---

1. Filter all beans that are marked with `@Service` annotation.
2. Filter all methods that have the marker annotation `@Refreshable` over themselves.
3. Perform the specified method on the return objects of these methods.

Below is my working example:

```java
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface Refreshable {
}
```

```java
public interface VisitServiceI {

    @Refreshable
    VisitDtoOut addVisitToPatient(UUID idPatient, VisitDtoIn visitDtoIn);

}
```

```java
public interface RefreshableDto {

    void copyId();

}
```

```java
@Component
public class MethodBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        if (bean instanceof VisitServiceI) {
            ProxyFactory factory = new ProxyFactory(bean);
            factory.addInterface(VisitServiceI.class);
            factory.addAdvice((AfterReturningAdvice) (returnValue, method, args, target) -> {
                if (method.isAnnotationPresent(Refreshable.class)) {
                    var refreshableDto = (RefreshableDto) returnValue;
                    if (refreshableDto != null) {
                        refreshableDto.copyId();
                    }
                }
            });
            factory.setExposeProxy(true);
            return factory.getProxy();
        }
        return bean;
    }

}
```

---

Is this possible to get rid of that useless interfaces like: `VisitServiceI`
I want to force `BeanPostProcessor` to somehow works when I will give him standard classes instead of interfaces of them.

Comment: Howelse would you force the implementation of a method other than with an interface? I would say the useless thing here is the annotation not the interface.

Comment: Why do you think annotation is useless? I want to proxy only specific methods. With annotation I can explicit say which method need to be included.

Comment: Create a proxy for the given class (like spring does). Also this looks like quite easy to implement with an aspect insteda of using a `BeanPostProcessor`. So not sure what this adds over a regular Aspect.

Comment: Yes I know this can be achieve with Aspect too but I am trying to do it with BeanPostProcessor for educational purposes.

Comment: There is nothing educational in solving a problem in the wrong way imho. on the `ProxyFactory` set `proxyTargetClass` to `true` to get a class proxy or if you now it are only interfaces just remove the `addInterface` as the proxy factory already detects implemented interfaces. Your problem is your `instanceof` for the service you need to check the `@Service` annotation on the class (as that is your requirement not checkig the interface).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ditch the `BeanPostProcessor` and just write an aspect instead, let Spring do the heavy lifting.

```
@Aspect
@Component
public RefreshableAspect {

 @AfterReturn("within(@Service) && @annotation(@Refreshable)", returning="retVal")
public void refresh(Object retVal) {
  if (retVal instanceof RefreshableDto) {
    ((RefreshableDto) retVal).copyId();
  }
} 

}
```

Something like that will accomplish what you need without interfaces and without an additional `BeanPostProcessor`.

But if you really want the complex route do something like this

```java
@Component
public class MethodBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        if (AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(bean.getClass(), Service.class) != null) {
            ProxyFactory factory = new ProxyFactory(bean);
            factory.setProxyTargetClass(true);
            factory.addAdvice((AfterReturningAdvice) (returnValue, method, args, target) -> {
                if (method.isAnnotationPresent(Refreshable.class)) {
                    var refreshableDto = (RefreshableDto) returnValue;
                    if (refreshableDto != null) {
                        refreshableDto.copyId();
                    }
                }
            });
            factory.setExposeProxy(true);
            return factory.getProxy();
        }
        return bean;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but you forgot `setProxyTargetClass(true);`

Comment: Which isn't strictly needed if you are only using interfaces (as the `ProxyFactory` detects those already).

Comment: True but I don't want those interfaces but anyway big thanks!

Comment: You already have the interface, so not sure why you don't want an interface based proxy?

Comment: Because in my opinion those interfaces are not necessary. I want to get rid of them.

Comment: WHy did you create those in the first place?

Comment: That was the point of this topic. I didn't know how to achieve it without interfaces so I created them.